# How to check for local time 02:30am without running into Winter/Summer time problems

Tags: c#, timezone

I have a program where world-wide users shall be able to configure that a task always runs at X:YZ o'clock. In their local time, all year round.

I thought about storing the timestamp in UTC offset but that brings the problem that half a year there is an hour difference between the configured time and the calculated time based on UTC. (example when I configure it to be 10:00 in Germany on Nov 25th, it'll be 09:00 UTC. But in May it suddenly will be 11:00 in Germany because now the UTC offset is two hours.

However, storing just the time in the database brings the problem that some hours simply don't exist on certain days of the year. When the clock is moved forward, the time jumps from 1:59 directly to 3:00. Any time between 2:00 and 2:59 on that particular day is invalid.

But how do I figure out that a certain time on a certain day in a certain timezone is invalid?

**Edit**
I tested [`TimeZoneInfo.IsInvalid()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.isinvalidtime?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.TimeZoneInfo.IsInvalidTime);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) but it doesn't appear to work:

On Sunday, 29th March 2020 there was no hour 02:30am. And yet `IsInvalid()` reports `false`:

```
var tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time");
var isInvalid = tzi.IsInvalidTime(new DateTime(2020, 3, 29, 2, 30, 0, DateTimeKind.Local));
```

**Edit 2**

Ah ok, one needs to mark the timestamp as unspecified for `IsInvalidTime()` to work properly:

```
var isInvalid = tzi.IsInvalidTime(new DateTime(2020, 3, 29, 2, 30, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified));
```

Comment: Always store and operate with times in the UTC format. Only for displaying purposes convert it to your local time. That way you don't have to deal with the timezones.

Comment: But then the task is run at 08:30 half a year and 09:30 the other half. That's not what the user wants nor what he configured.

Comment: Is each instance of an application entirely separate or do they talk to a central service?

Comment: Central configuration and job execution service. And that service needs to know that it is 5:00 am right now at where the user is

Answer (score 0):

[`TimeZoneInfo.IsInvalid()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.isinvalidtime?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.TimeZoneInfo.IsInvalidTime);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) does work if the `DateTime` object is created properly. It must not have the `DateTimeKind.Local` attribute but rather `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`

```
var tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time");
var isInvalid = tzi.IsInvalidTime(new DateTime(2020, 3, 29, 2, 30, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified));
```